# Unable to connect to remote PostgresSQL server with JDBC driver

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a remote PostgreSQL database using JDBC, however the connection times out. 
To be able to access the remote server I'm connected to a tunnel. There is no problem when I'm  trying to connect from the same network with JDBC, only remotely.

I'm able to connect to the database both remotely and locally using other tools (e.g. pgAdmin, HeidiSQL, python sqlalchemy/psycopg2), but not with JDBC. I do not need to add other options for remote connection with the other tools, simply host:port and user/pass.

Searching for solutions I have tried the following without success:

- add property `"ssl"` with value `"true"` to the driver connection
- add property `"sslfactory"` with value `"org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory"`
- add property `"loginTimeout"` with value `20`
- set `listen_addresses = '*'` in `postgresql.conf` on remote server
- add `host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0          md5` to  `pg_hba.conf` on remote server

Using driver version `postgresql-42.2.14`. I'm attempting to connect using SQuirreL and MATLAB.

As other tools have no issue connecting I'm guessing this is about tweaking the JDBC settings.
What am I missing here?

Edit:
Trying to ping the IP of the remote server (192.168.x.x.) I get:

`Reply from 10.x.x.x: Destination net unreachable.`

At the same time I'm able to connect to the database on the same server IP. Is this a clue to the problem?

Connection url:
`jdbc:postgresql://192.168.x.x:5432/<dbname>`

Results of `Test-NetConnection`

```
PS > Test-NetConnection 192.168.x.x
WARNING: Ping to 192.168.x.x failed with status:
DestinationNetworkUnreachable                                         
PS > Test-NetConnection 192.168.x.x -port 5432                                                     

ComputerName     : 192.168.x.x
RemoteAddress    : 192.168.x.x
RemotePort       : 5432
InterfaceAlias   : Local Area Connection 3
SourceAddress    : 192.168.x.x
TcpTestSucceeded : True
```

Running `tracert 192.168.x.x`

```
  Tracing route to 192.168.x.x over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.1
  2  10.x.x.x  reports: Destination net unreachable.

Trace complete.
```

Stacktrace (SQuirreL):

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:81)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:93)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:197)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:217)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.sql.SQLDriverManager.getConnection(SQLDriverManager.java:147)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.executeConnect(OpenConnectionCommand.java:136)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.lambda$execute$0(OpenConnectionCommand.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: "*Destination net unreachable*" points to a network problem, e.g. a firewall on the target server blocking connections. This happens _before_ the Postgres server even sees the connection attempt.

Comment: thanks @a_horse_with_no_name! I'll contact the server admin and ask - although it strikes me as strange since I'm able to connect to the remote database using other drivers?

Comment: Does jdbc use a different port or protocol than TCP? I get `TcpTestSucceeded : True` running `Test-NetConnection 192.168.x.x -port 5432` in powershell

Answer (score 0):

You are pinging IP address in the range of 192.168.x.x and getting reply from 10.x.x.x. Those are two different sub-nets.

As odd as it seems, it does not go well with your initial statement about being able to connect via other means. If network was issue then other tools would have failed as well. Not getting a reply for ping "Request time out" is expected result if there is blockage.

"Destination unreachable" means there is no proper route available to the IP you are trying to get to. With that issue, no other connections to that host should be reachable from your host.

Please confirm if all connections you attempted were from same client host. Also have you tried ODBC connector to see if that works? That allows System DSNs and you do not need to do much in attempt to connect.

Please make sure you do tests either from same hosts or two machines on same network to simplify things.

With "Destination unreachable" error your client should not be talking to server in anyway if same destination IP is used.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will look into ODBC. All connections are made from the same client (same computer), and only via JDBC it fails. I also added some results from Test-NetConnection in the original post

Comment: It seems your host has multiple Network adapters. Could be that adapter that is suppose to connect to 192.*.*.* is not the primary adapter. You can change the sequence in network setting. Try running tracert to the IP and see what you get.

Comment: I added the tracert result in the post. ODBC connection works fine (tested via ODBC Administrator and added under System DNS). My networking knowledge is worse than bad, so a lot of this is over my head.